# What is the (algebraic) dimension of the dual of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb F (=\mathbb R$ or $ \mathbb C$). If $\alpha$ is the dimension of $V$, for some cardinal number $\alpha$, I want to know, what is the dimension of $V^*$, the algebraic dual of $V$?

Answer (score -1):

if $\dim V$ is finite its the same as $V$, given a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$, yo can made a dual basis as follows, for $i=1,\dots,n$ define $v^i:V\to \mathbb F$, such that $v^i(v_j) = \delta^i_j$,  (Kronecker delta) for all $i,j$ Just remember that you can define a linear map only giving it's values in a given basis.

they span $V^*$, for every $f \in V^*$, $f= \sum f(v_i)v^i$
and they are independient, for if $0 = \alpha_1v^1+\cdots + \alpha_nv^n$, evaluating in $v_j$ gives $\alpha_j = 0$ for all $j$

if $\alpha $ is not finite, the dimension of the dual is bigger. Even when we restrict to the topological dual the dimension "increases"

Comment: And an important point here is that if $\alpha$ is not finite (which is possible as described by OP), this construction does not work

Comment: I think the question is about infinite dimensional case. As far as I know $\dim(V^{\ast})=|\mathrm{F}|^{\dim(V)}$ for infinite dimensional $V$. Here $\mathrm{F}$ is the field.